# How are dependent projects in Jenkins supposed to work?

Tags: jenkins

I have a shell script project in jenkins that has a Post-Build action of Build Other Projects.  I list two project (comma delimited), but only the first one ever builds.  How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Get **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**. Does the same thing, but much better.

When configuring **Post-build actions**, do the following:

- Select **Trigger parameterized build on other projects** action
- Specify first project to build
- Click **Add trigger...** button
- Specify second project to build